# How do I add iDEAL as a payment method to my Stripe payment sheet/intent in React Native and PHP (Laravel) backend?

Tags: react-native, stripe-payments, payment

I am building a payment screen for a React Native app with a Laravel backend. Right now I have my the payment intent/sheet working for credit card, with the following code:

React Native:

```
try {
  const response = await axios.post(
    `${API_BASE_URL}/store-order`,
    {
      company_id: cart[0].company_id,
      name: name,
      address: address,
      phone: phone,
      email: email,
      company: company,
      products: cart,
      price: getTotalPrice(),
      // delivery_at: delivery_at,
    },
    {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
      },
    }
  );

  if (response.data) {
    const { clientSecret, orderId } = response.data;

    const { error } = await initPaymentSheet({
      paymentIntentClientSecret: clientSecret,
    });

    if (!error) {
      // Handle the confirmation of payment here
      handlePayment(clientSecret, orderId);
    }
  }
}

const handlePayment = async (clientSecret, orderId) => {

const { error } = await presentPaymentSheet({ clientSecret });

if (error) {
  const newClientSecret = await fetchNewClientSecret(orderId);

  if (newClientSecret) {
    // Re-initialize the PaymentSheet with the new client secret
    const { error: initError } = await initPaymentSheet({
      paymentIntentClientSecret: newClientSecret,
    });

    if (initError) {
      console.log(
        `PaymentSheet re-initialization failed: ${initError.message}`
      );
    } else {
      // Try the payment again
      await handlePayment(newClientSecret, orderId);
    }
  } else {
    console.log("Failed to fetch a new client secret");
  }
} else {
  const response = await axios.post(
    `${API_BASE_URL}/pay-order`,
    {
      order_id: orderId,
    },
    {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
      },
    }
  );

  if (response.data.message == "Order paid.") {
    navigation.navigate("DrawerNavigation");
  } else {
    Alert.alert("Payment Failed", "Do you want to retry?", [
      { text: "No", style: "cancel" },
      { text: "Yes", onPress: () => handlePayment(clientSecret, orderId) },
    ]);
  }
}
```

Laravel:

(store-order)

```
Stripe::setApiKey(env('STRIPE_SECRET'));

$paymentIntent = PaymentIntent::create([
    'amount' => $price * 100, // amount should be in cents
    'currency' => 'eur',
]);
```

(pay-order)

```
Stripe::setApiKey(env('STRIPE_SECRET'));
$paymentIntent = PaymentIntent::retrieve($order->payment_intent);
```

I want to add iDEAL as a payment method to the intent/sheet. How can I do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can follow this step-by-step guide for integrating IDEAL with Stripe PaymentSheet:

https://stripe.com/docs/payments/ideal/accept-a-payment?platform=mobile

You need to add payment_methods:

```
$stripe->paymentIntents->create([
  'amount' => $price * 100,
  'currency' => 'eur',
  'payment_method_types' => ['ideal'],
]);
```

Or you can use [automatic_payment_methods](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/create?lang=php#create_payment_intent-automatic_payment_methods-enabled):

```
$stripe->paymentIntents->create([
  'amount' => $price * 100,
  'currency' => 'eur',
  'automatic_payment_methods' => [
     'enabled' => true,
  ],
]);
```

Make sure to activate [IDEAL in your dashboard](https://dashboard.stripe.com/settings/payment_methods).

Comment: I am getting the following error:
The operation couldn’t be completed. (StripePaymentSheet.PaymentSheetError error 1.)

Comment: It is probably because I have not activated my account 100% yet. I'll try it when the account is 100% verified! Thanks for your help!